# Metadata failed setting attribute

Tags: command-line, gedit, metadata

When I run command gedit for any purpose for example gedit Mac.sh it shows a warning or message that set documents metadata failed setting attribute metadata.
Please provide me a solution on this in an easy understanding language.

Comment: We will have the best chances of helping if you're providing full details. Please start with your OS & release, and copy/paste the command & error messages exactly as you see them (*adding those into your question, not as a reply via comment*).

Comment: ** (gedit:4113): WARNING **:10:18:××.×××: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

Comment: OS & release details; command and error message should be added to your question (*not a reply via comment*).  From your provided comment; you've not ruled out an invalid command, let alone warnings are also not errors.

Comment: I was trying to add Mac.sh in document but after doing gedit mac.sh and coding, it displays various warning. So, can you fix it?

Comment: I don't understand your issue; for starters what system you're using (a standard Ubuntu release; Ubuntu Core release with *confinement* model etc), can't see your command (*which likely explains the message you provided in my opinion*) etc.

Comment: I am using Kali linux on virtual box

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Kali forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Kali so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)  See also https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 0):

The auto installer is trying to install from a http site not a https site. These  know it all's don't see the forest because of the trees. Ubuntu doesn't exist anymore at the auto-installer site. Goto the new site and download a fresh copy. https://ubuntu.com/download

Comment: This answer does not appear to address the question asked.  Are you sure you have the right post?